# Actual usages for C multibyte character constants

Tags: c, char, multibyte-characters

Can anybody help me understand the actual usages of **multibyte character constants** in C?

I have seen the following code working just fine, and I want to understand what the actual usage of this language feature is. (I know that defining them is standard C; accessing them, however, is *not* standard conformant). Someone pointed out to me that these multibyte character constants are useful on platforms like Classic MacOS, but they failed to be able to provide an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    (void) 'this'; // this seems to be standard conformant

    // but what can we do with this "feature"?
    // This compiles and runs just fine, but is a crude hack:
    long i = 'this';
    const char* u = (const char*) &i;
    const unsigned z = sizeof(long)/sizeof(char);
    printf("%u\n", z);

    for(unsigned v = 0; v < z; v++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", (char)u[v]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Code output was requested (see here: https://godbolt.org/z/ebsTj4a9E):

```
8
s
i
h
t
```

Comment: Here is the full set of valid uses: `{}`.

Comment: Per the standard (C23, N3096 6.4.4.4/11) _"The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., ’ab’), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single value in the literal encoding, is implementation-defined."_. No portable meaning makes them pretty much useless. There's nothing stopping a compiler from deciding that `'one' == 1`, or some other domain-specific special meaning.

Comment: Ok thank you @Brian61354270 If I understand that correctly, we can define them just fine, doing anything else then casting them to void like this ´(void) 'this'´ is undefined. But I swear that I heard that classic macOS had a good use for them, I will update this question if I find out more about it.

Comment: @johnworchester To be clear, it's implementation defined behavior, not undefined behavior. The two terms have different meaning. See [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/11082165) and C23/N3096 3.4.

Comment: @Brian61354270: “No portable meaning makes them pretty much useless” is not a valid inference. Portability is not a requirement for all projects. It is entirely valid, and useful to many people, to program for a specific C implementation.

Comment: they're quite useful for defining magic 4 byte values used in file formats, e.g. the box types in MP4/MOV files, not being portable does make them difficult to use in cross platform code

Comment: It’s been a long time, but it used to be that computing was expensive and compiler optimization was limited. Being able to write C code that handled multiple characters at one time was a time-saver (processor time saver). The particulars of multibyte constants were not standardized because some platforms put the characters in one order, some put them in another order, and some used non-ASCII character sets. Today you can expect a compiler will consolidate multiple individual byte operations and using multibyte constants would make little difference, but that was not always the case.

Comment: `(void) 'this'`; has very well defined behaviour. It does nothing.

Comment: As an aside, it's not necessary to divide by `sizeof(char)` since by definition it is `1`.

Comment: Windows kernel uses 4 byte tags in `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` that are printed as 4 characters, and they are usually defined using multibyte character constants, but they are usually written backwards in the source for little endian reasons.

Comment: @johnworchester, `(void) 'this'; // this seems to be standard conformant` is a problem when the sizeof `int` is 2.

Comment: @johnworchester 1) `long i = 'this';` --> `long` here is curious.  `i` is being initialize with a  constant of type `int`.  "An integer character constant has type `int`."   2) Why wasn't your code output included in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anybody help me understand the actual usages of **multibyte character constants** in C?

Your wording is a bit of a melange as far as the language spec's terminology goes, but then the spec uses a confusing set of similar terms for similar, but distinct concepts.  Among them

- "**character**" in the sense of *abstract character*: "member of a set of elements used for the organization, control, or representation of data";
- "**character**" / "**single-byte character**", in the sense of a collection of bits that fits in one byte;
- "**multi-byte character**": a sequence of one or more bytes representing a member of the [source or execution] extended character set; as opposed to
- "**wide character**": a value representable by an object of type `wchar_t`;
- "**character constant**" / "**integer character constant**": a lexical element of C source code, consisting of a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single quotes.

That's a bit of a mess, I think you'll agree, but to its credit, at least the spec avoids throwing the term "multibyte character constant" into the mix as well.

I think what you're talking about is what the spec describes as "an integer character constant containing more than one character [...] or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character".  The values of such constants have type `int`, as do all character constants, but their values are implementation defined.

> I know that defining them is standard C; accessing them, however, is not standard conformant

No, that's not a good description.  Character constants containing multiple single-byte characters are *lexically valid*, and, supposing that the implementation accepts them, their values are implementation defined.  The spec does not actually bind implementations to accept such constants, however, neither in general nor any particular ones.  That's a bit of a problem for "defining them is standard C".  On the other hand, in implementations that do accept them, they serve as ordinary constants with whatever `int` values the implementation attributes to them.  In that sense, there is no inherent issue with accessing them.

**The main issue with these is that they are not portable**, in the sense that different implementations may attribute different numeric values to the same lexical constant.  In truth, however, this is a difference of magnitude, not kind, for exactly the same is true of character constants formed of individual single-byte characters.

The thing that distinguishes character constants formed of individual single-byte characters is exactly that they *do* map to individual members of the execution character set, in a predictable way.  If you need a portable program then you need to avoid character constants of the kind you ask about.  However, **if you are content with code that you can rely upon to work correctly only on certain implementations**, then "implementation defined" means that the values of such constants are defined, and conforming implementations must each document their definitions.  For example, since at least version 4.0, GCC has used this definition:

> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type `int`, and is therefore signed [...]. If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target `int` [...] the excess leading characters are ignored.

([GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior))

You can rely on that as long as you stick to GCC and any other implementation that guarantees compatibility with GCC in this area.  And you might not even need specific values to match across implementations, as long as different constants of interest to you (not exceeding some maximum length, say) can be relied upon to have different values.

### But what can you actually do with them?

There's not much that I would *actually* do with them, myself, but I can imagine them being used

- mnemonically, somewhat like enumeration constants (but I would actually use enumeration constants here)
- as a direct mapping to keywords of a language featuring keywords that are universally short enough. That is, one might read in a keyword, convert it to a number, and compare that to various multi-character character constants (but I would probably choose a different approach, maybe a hash table).
- in other, non-specific ways I have yet to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example where I used to use them (until things broke):

```
switch (code) {
    // Pen up
    case 'pu':
        ...
    // Pen down
    case 'pd':
        ...
    // Plot absolute
    case 'pa':
        ...
    // Plot relative
    case 'pr':
        ...
    ...
}
```

This was part of a parser for HPGL (Hewlett Packard Graphics Language) used by plotters.

The next time we upgraded the compiler, the new compiler rejected that code or the compiled binary failed to work as desired, I don't remember which, so we had to rewrite it.

Conclusion: Don't use them, they are useless. :)

Comment: Nothing in this answer sustains its purported “conclusion.”

Comment: Care to elaborate, @EricPostpischil?

Comment: The first part of this answer gives an example where multibyte characters were used. That proves they have a use. The second part gives an example where the existing code for multibyte characters did not work. The fact there is a situation in which existing code did not work (a) does not prove it would not have worked if changed, and (b) in no way negates the fact there was a situation in which they did have a use. Therefore the conclusion that multibyte constants are useless is not demonstrated in any way.

Comment: Sorry, but the fact that they were used does not prove that they have a use, under the implied assumption that "a use" means something that is solid software engineering. If I didn't attach that implied assumption, I could also prove that undefined behaviour has a use, so I think that reasoning is sound. Now, the example use was not reliable and it isn't something that's inherently restricted to an environment where such nonportable code works, let alone is required. I would argue that this does not constitute solid engineering. Could you write an answer here that illustrates good use perhaps?

Comment: Re “Sorry, but the fact that they were used does not prove that they have a use…”: ROTFL. Re “I could also prove that undefined behaviour has a use”: Undefined behavior does have uses. Leaving some things undefined was an important design principle in C. It was not designed so that any code could be ported anywhere, it was designed so the language itself could be ported to many systems. So some things were left undefined so they could be customized to target systems. This provided a common language enabling programmer skills in that language to be useful in diverse systems…

Comment: … That was new thing at one time. C made it easier to work with new systems. Various things that are “undefined” in the C standard are usefully defined in some systems. Re “Now, the example use was not reliable…”: Nothing in the answer shows that. The code was apparently fine in its original situation. The fact it did not serve in a new situation does not mean it was not reliable for its original purpose. **You** may value portability, but that does not mean every project needs it or there is anything wrong with no designing for portability.

Comment: Re “I would argue that this does not constitute solid engineering”: Solid engineering does not mean writing portable code. It means writing code that conforms to its specification. There is no universal requirement that a specification contain portability as one of its requirements.

Comment: It's okay, you're totally right.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody help me understand the actual usages of multibyte character constants in C?

`'this'` is called an *integer character constant*.  It has type `int`.

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one **or more** multibyte characters enclosed in single quotes, as in `’x’`. ... C23dr § 6.4.4.4 2

> An integer character constant has type `int`. ... § 6.4.4.4 11

There are many implementation specific attributes to *integer character constants* of more than 1 character that limit portability.  **When portability is important**, rarely are *integer character constants* of more than 1 character used.

**When portability is not important**, *integer character constants* of more than 1 character such as `'ab'` (when `sizeof(int)` >= 2), `'this'` (when `sizeof(int)` >= 4) may be used like *integer character constants* of 1 character like `'a'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int parse_text_to_dir(const char *s);
void report_invalid_movement(void);
extern int room;
extern int secret_room;

int main(void) {
  char s[80];
  switch (parse_text_to_dir(fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin))) {
    case 'n' :
    case 's' : room = room; break; // loop back
    case 'e' : room++; break;
    case 'w' : room--; break;
    case 'ne' : room = secret_room; break;
    default: report_invalid_movement();
  }
```

- Advantage: Code does not need a `enum direction` as the enumeration name is implied with the constant value itself.  This is much like code that says `if (answer == 'y') {`, but is extended to 2 characters to handle a direction like `'ne'`.
- Disadvantage: The above reason is generally out of modern coding styles and a `enum direction { dir_n, dir_ne, dir_e, ...};` is preferred.
- Disadvantage: Forming the equivalent value of `'this'` from single characters is tricky due to endian, `sizeof(int)`, `char` signed-ness, .. and tends to be error prone.

```
enum dir { dir_n, dir_ne, dir_e, dir_se, dir_s, dir,sw, dir_w, dir_nw, dir_up, dir_dn };
enum dir parse_text_to_dir(const char *s);
void report_invalid_movement(void);
extern int room;
extern int secret_room;

int main(void) {
  char s[80];
  switch (parse_text_to_dir(fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin))) {
    case dir_n :
    case dir_s : room = room; break; // loop back
    case dir_e : room++; break;
    case dir_w : room--; break;
    case dir_ne : room = secret_room; break;
    default: report_invalid_movement();
  }
```